# How to add text in blender using python and Control Location and scale

Tags: python, scripting, text-object

I ran into a problem with texts and python in blender scripting.

```
def main(context):
    font_curve = bpy.data.curves.new(type="FONT", name="numberPlate")
    font_curve.body = (numberPlate)
    font_obj = bpy.data.objects.new(name="Font Object", object_data=font_curve)
    bpy.context.scene.collection.objects.link(font_obj)
```

I'm currently using this to add in a custom text but I also want to have control over the scale and location of the text I am adding in.

I'm a python beginner and I don't know how else to go about it as I have tried everything I know.

Would appreciate your help. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using Blender 3.0.0
Just set location and scale after making the object

```
font_curve = bpy.data.curves.new(type="FONT", name="numberPlate")
font_curve.body = "ABC123"
obj = bpy.data.objects.new(name="Font Object", object_data=font_curve)

# -- Set scale and location
obj.location = (-1, 1, 0)
obj.scale = (0.75, 0.5, 0.5)
bpy.context.scene.collection.objects.link(obj)
```

Comment: Whew. That worked plenty.
Thank you.

Comment: You are welcome! I remember being a beginner too :)